# How to locate SubView in MainView for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to locate the subView in MainView when i clicked UIButton.
But when i clicked that Button,that subView is only appear at the top of the MainView.
I want to appear that subView in the below of the mainView with Slide that like keyboard.
In iOS,keyboard appears in the below of the mainView with slide.
I want to appear my SubView like that.
How can i do that?
Please help me!.

Best Regards,

Comment: Your question is too broad and vague.  You need to show us what you've tried.  You need to tell us what experience you have programming iOS.  You need to tell us what documentation you've read to find an answer.  You need to tell us what web searches you've done to find an answer.

Comment: I don't have any experience in iOS.Just a beginner.I already search in Google.But i didn't found what i want.If i already know how to make it,i don't have to ask a question here!

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading the [documentation for UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html). Almost all drawing in iOS is done by classes derived from UIView, so you'll need to be very familiar with it. In UIView you'll find the [`-addSubview:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview%3a) method, which you can use to add a subview to any view.

If you want the subview to slide into place, you'll want to read about Core Animation.

If the subview is meant for input, like a keyboard replacement, you can instead look at the `inputView` property that certain views (e.g. UITextField and UITextView) provide. If you the `inputView` property for, say, a text field to your view, the system will take care of presenting your view when that text field becomes the first responder.